# Is there a DESCRIBE function for Django Models?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to know the columns in a table. Is there a `DESCRIBE table;` in django?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use model._meta.get_all_field_names() to get a list of all the fields in a model class.

Comment: Thanks. It shows foreign key models too. Is there a way to exclude foreign keys, i.e., only show columns within the class?

Comment: You can use model._meta.get_field() to get more info about the individual fields, including if it is a ForeignKey.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `./manage.py sqlall <app name>` to print the SQL used to create the table for a given app. For the tutorial project's polls app the output is:

```
tutorial% ./manage.py sqlall polls
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "polls_poll" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "polls_choice" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "poll_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "polls_poll" ("id"),
    "choice" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "votes" integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE INDEX "polls_choice_763e883" ON "polls_choice" ("poll_id");
COMMIT;
```

Which you might find useful.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I found is to use `print Class.__doc__`, for example:

```
>>> from network.models import Network
>>> print Network.__doc__
Network(id, network, name, location)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also browse your models' fields and documentation through the admindocs app ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/ ) :

> Django’s admindocs app pulls
>   documentation from the docstrings of
>   models, views, template tags, and
>   template filters for any app in
>   INSTALLED_APPS and makes that
>   documentation available from the
>   Django admin.